# Firebase inApp flutter notificaiton is not working and showing no error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

here is the code i done. and it works perfectly fine. i tried debugging and the post method is posting everything properly. but the notification is not receiving.
here is the whole code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  Future<bool> callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications(
      {required String title, required String body}) async {
    const postUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    final data = {
      "to": "/topics/myTopic",
      "notification": {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
      },
      "data": {
        "type": '0rder',
        "id": '28',
        "click_action": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      }
    };

    final headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':
          'key=AAAAMKtOtwQ:APA91bFCCEwWKU75EVeyc912ghzS0Yon8dlfjiFEiw9nfdtfrq0BCBWS3x_ioTqX1l2MUDO_Wb-c2PbRl66Z_2mvFEsPRbDEAPTSCEb7SVFykecC_BWGR5P2La8T47eIfCiMvU9oJDJd'
    };

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postUrl),
        body: json.encode(data),
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
        headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('test ok push CFM');
      return true;
    } else {
      print(' CFM error');
      return false;
    }
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications(
          title: 'fcm by api2', body: 'its working fine2');
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

is there anything i need to fix from firebase or any problem with the code. i can't figure it out please help me

i tried debugging and printing everywhere in the code file. and everything work fine. and i enabled everything ive to do from firebase. still not getting a notification

also I'm testing this in android

Comment: Your are using android ?

Comment: @7eg yes im using android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting messages, you will need a way to handle those messages and it will depend if the message is received while the app is in the foreground, background or closed.

This [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_messages) shows how to setup the listener for messages received in the foreground:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

This [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#apple_platforms_and_android) shows how to do this for messages received while in the background:

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You can see how these methods are implemented in this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-flutter/blob/main/messaging/lib/main.dart).

Then, to receive the messages you will need to suscribe to the topics. In the sample I mentioned, you can see this in the method:

```dart
Future<void> subscribeToTopic(String topic) async {
    await firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to `/topics/myTopic` topic.

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("/topics/myTopic");
```

See [Topic messaging on Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/topic-messaging) for the details.

Remember that messages received while the application is in the foreground will not display a visible notification.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include this line  `'origin': 'http://localhost',` in your header to make it act like if you are using browser...so, your header should be like this:

```
  final headers = {
  'origin': 'http://localhost',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization':
      'key=AAAAMKtOtwQ:APA91bFCCEwWKU75EVeyc912ghzS0Yon8dlfjiFEiw9nfdtfrq0BCBWS3x_ioTqX1l2MUDO_Wb-c2PbRl66Z_2mvFEsPRbDEAPTSCEb7SVFykecC_BWGR5P2La8T47eIfCiMvU9oJDJd'
};
```

Comment: still not working